# Django + Apache - Can't find directory of my website

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have done a website by using django framework. Now I'm trying to deploy using apache+wsgi. Here is my setting.
So I have a ip 59.120.185.12 and here is my .config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.vbgetech.com
    ServerAlias vbgetech.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    Alias /media/ /home/max/v_bridge/media/
    Alias /static/ /home/max/v_bridge/static/

    <Directory /home/max/v_bridge/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/max/v_bridge/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/max/v_bridge/v_bridge/wsgi.py


    <Directory /home/max/v_bridge/v_bridge/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And its my wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for website project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from os.path import join,dirname,abspath

PROJECT_DIR = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))#3
import sys # 4
sys.path.insert(0,PROJECT_DIR) # 5

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "v_bridge.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I think I do follow all the instruction by official document. And It seems that If I type the ip on browser it still return me a apache default page. I guess that is because my server can't map the ip to the .conf file. Anyone has idea about it?

Comment: What is ".config"? Where exactly is that file?

Comment: .conf is a configuration file in apache2/sites-available

Comment: Is it linked to sites-enabled? Have you restarted Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the site using the URL `http://www.vbgetech.com`. You can't necessarily use the IP address. If you use the IP it will not match by host name lookup against `VirtualHost` and so the request will instead be handled by the first `VirtualHost` in the Apache configuration file, or in other words the default `VirtualHost`. That default `VirtualHost` is going to give you the default page if you never changed it.

In other words, if you added a new `VirtualHost` and didn't modify the default one, then you are going to have to use a proper host name in the URL for it to match your `VirtualHost`.

Comment: Is that mean I can only access the site using the url instead of ip?

Comment: If you use the IP, it will go to the default ``VirtualHost``, which is the first one that Apache reads from the configuration files. If that isn't the ``VirtualHost`` your application is set up in, then you will not get your site as you expect. If you don't have a real domain that can setup in a DNS, you would have to create fake hostname in ``/etc/hosts`` mapping to your IP, or use an ``xip.io`` style address and use it for ``ServerName``. Eg., ``myhost.1.2.3.4.xip.io`` where ``1.2.3.4`` is your IP, and then set ``ServerName`` to ``myhost.1.2.3.4.xip.io``. Then access site with that host.

Comment: "If you use the IP it will not match by host name lookup against VirtualHost and so the request will instead be handled by the first VirtualHost." Why the ip will not a match by host name lookup? I thought if I use dns it will translate to ip and use this ip to lookup for desire virtualhost.

Comment: You indicated you are putting the IP address in your browser, not the host name. If you use the same host name in URL of browser that matches ``ServerName`` and that has an associated IP address in DNS/hosts file that matches your server fine. You keep mentioning using IP though, that is not the host. You can't though put IP as a ``ServerName`` or ``ServerAlias`` as browsers see it as an IP in URL and don't set ``Host`` header, which is what Apache uses for name base virtual host matching.

Comment: So In the case i dont have a real dns yet. I have to set my /etc/hosts like this "59.120.185.12  v_bridge" and in my conf I set servername to "ServerName v_bridge.59.120.185.12.xip.ip" And browse my site with " v_bridge.59.120.185.12.xip.ip". Is that right?

Comment: If you are going to use ``xip.io`` you don't need to modify you ``/etc/hosts`` file to get Apache to work. Just set ``ServerName`` to ``v_bridge.59.120.185.12.xip.io`` and then use URL of ``http://v_bridge.59.120.185.12.xip.io`` in browser. What ``xip.io`` does is provide a DNS service where it will return that IP embedded in hostname as target of that hostname. Thus maps back to your machine.